# The same input jar [\..\Android\sdk\platforms\android-26\android.jar] is specified twice

Tags: java, android-studio

I am  having a  problem with my project when I try to create a build from my android studio. Platform-26 is specified twice. I have deleted Plateform-26 from plateforms of my android sdk but still it is showing error

```
dependencies {
   compile project(path: ':HeaderListView')
   compile project(path: ':MPChartLib')
   //compile files('libs/okhttp-3.4.1.jar')
   compile('com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.7.0') {
    force = true
  }

 compile('com.squareup.okio:okio:1.10.0') {
    force = true

   }
   compile('com.peekaboo.connect:sdk:2.0.70') {
    exclude module: 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7'
    exclude group: 'com.facebook.infer'
  }
  //    compile(name: 'peekaboo-guru-sdk', ext: 'aar')
  //    compile project(':react-native-config')
  //    compile project(path: ':safetynetlib')
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2'
  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.2'
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.2'
  compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.2'
  //    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:9.8.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
  compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
  compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
  compile 'se.simbio.encryption:library:1.2.0'
  compile 'com.itextpdf:itextpdf:5.3.2'
  compile 'com.scottyab:rootbeer-lib:0.0.4'
  compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.2'
  compile files('libs/dexguard-runtime.jar')
  compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
  compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
  compile 'com.github.lzyzsd:circleprogress:1.2.1'
  compile 'pl.bclogic:pulsator4droid:1.0.3'
  compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.35.0'
   //    //Firebase
   compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
}
```

Following is Exception

```
  org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task 
  ':app:dexguardRelease'.
    at 
  org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter
 .executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
```

Comment: any resolution?